# Can PowerMock be used without annotations?

Tags: java, clojure, annotations, mocking, powermock

I'm trying to use PowerMock as a library in another application. Is there a way to use it to mock a static method call without using annotations (I'm in Clojure which doesn't really do annotations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [powermock](http://groups.google.com/group/powermock/browse_thread/thread/f7df24bddf1cc73) support and [this blog](http://kirkgsworld.blogspot.com/2010/04/powermock-mocking-statics-supplemental.html), I guess there is no way to avoid annotations in test.  I guess we need the `@PrepareForTest(StaticClass.class)` however.  So I believe it is not possible to avoid `@PrepareForTest` atleast.  May be I am wrong, but just thought of sharing what I found.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's possible, although the way to final solution is painful.

PowerMock runner just initializes test environment in different classloader, in which the classes specified in `PrepareForTest` annotation are tweaked by Javassist. So assumed you mimic the work of the classloader and call Javassist by yourself, you can achieve the same effect.

As an example, I utilized PowerMock (internals without annotations) to discover name of method for given method reference. Further info can be found on my [blog](http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2018/01/citelny-tostring-na-method-reference.html) (in Czech, with working examples). I emphasize such an usage is only experimental and not suitable for production usage.